# Does Google Analytics 3.17 for iOS using Cocoapods support Bitcode now?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, cocoapods

I just noticed an update to Google Analytics for iOS (3.17), and I'm wondering if it is safe to switch over to using this Cocoapod (https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAnalytics) and does it support Bitcode properly now?  There have been issues with these Cocoapods before.

Specifically, I've been using Google Analytics 3.15 in my app for months now, but I haven't used the Cocoapod, because it wasn't compiling for me (Google wasn't supporting Bitcode for iOS for the Cocoapod version of the code, if I remember correctly).  Somewhere I had read that by downloading the GoogleAnalyticsServices library directly (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download) and drag that into my project in Xcode, it would work, and would support Bitcode.  Which it has, and has worked well all this time.

But now I'd like to upgrade and change over to using it via Cocoapods if it supports Bitcode and is more officially supported by Google.

Anyone know?

Thanks.

---

PS. Which Version?

Google says to use the Cocoapod named:

`pod 'Google/Analytics'`

(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift)

While on Cocoapods.org, Google says to use this one:

`pod 'GoogleAnalytics'`

(https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAnalytics)

Which is the correct version to use?

Answer (score 2):

The `Google/Analytics pod` is the one that should be used when implementing Google Analytics in your iOS app. The `GoogleAnalytics` pod is not meant for direct use; we'll be updating the pod description.